# Why does a geoprocessing service fail every other time it is run?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, sql-server

I have a ArcGIS Server 10 geoprocessing service right now that takes in a string and runs a parameterized query to SQL Server 2008R2 through pyodbc. The service works, but only every other time. I can run it on my machine locally every time and also on the machine this runs on (also every time), but I can't run this through ArcGIS Server but every *other* time, either through the web interface or the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

Every other time, I get this error: `Error Executing Task. Error processing message`... along with a 500 error.

Is it maybe a problem with pyodbc? Or am I overlooking something small?

Here's what I'm working with (snipped SQL and a little extra). There's two input parameters, SearchTerm and SearchType (only can be "standard" in this snippet), and one output parameter. All parameters are strings.

```py
import arcpy
import pyodbc
import sys
import urllib

connection = None
cursor = None

def search(search_term, search_type):
    try:
        global connection
        search_term = urllib.unquote_plus(search_term)
        connection = pyodbc.connect(...)
        if search_type == "standard":
            return string_search(search_term) # snipped out other use case.
        else:
            return "[]"
    except:
        print_message(sys.exc_info(), True)
        return '{"error": "' + str(sys.exc_info()) + '"}'

def string_search(search_term):
    global cursor
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = """SELECT * FROM Resources WHERE ResourceName LIKE ?"""
    search_term = "%" + search_term.upper() + "%"
    cursor.execute(sql, search_term)
    return return_results()

def return_results():
    global connection
    global cursor
    return_ids = ""
    for row in cursor:
        resource_name = ""
        if row.ResourceName is None:
            resource_name = "Not Available"
        else:
            resource_name = row.ResourceName
        return_ids = return_ids + ',{"ResourceId":' + str(row.ResourceId) + '}'
    return_ids = return_ids[1:]
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return "[" + return_ids + "]"

def print_message(message, is_error=False):
    message = str(message)
    if is_error:
        print "ERROR: " + message
        arcpy.AddError(message)
    else:
        print message
        arcpy.AddMessage(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if arcpy.GetArgumentCount() > 0:
        return_text = search(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0), arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
        arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, return_text)
    else:
        arguments = ["chicken", "standard"]
        argv = tuple(arguments)
        print search(*argv)
```

Comment: Seems like pyodbc and ArcGIS geoprocessing services (even though it may be what ESRI recommends most of the time) don't get along.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced exactly the same problem earlier and was looking for the solution on the Internet. It seems as using [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) library works much better. I was able to publish a GP service and call stored procedures & perform multiple SQL statements obtaining as a result object record sets without any problem.

Pypyodbc is a pure Python ODBC interface module based on ctypes. It has the same [installation file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc/) (.py file), but since you will work with ArcGIS Server (64bit) yet publishing from ArcMap (32bit) you will need to install the library 2 times (each time specifying different Python path).

I've used cmd to get to a place for 32bit and 64bit Python installed and then called the setup.py file.

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe setup.py install
C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.2\python.exe setup.py install
```

**UPDATE:**
When having the GP service tested heavily for running multiple jobs executing many SQL statements including stored procedures, pypyodbc got crashed now and then with a general error.

**Solution:** use [`pymssql`](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/) (A simple database interface for Python that builds on top of FreeTDS to provide a Python DB-API (PEP-249) interface to Microsoft SQL Server) which works stable so far.